# multiprocessing - processes won't join?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

TL;DR - the consumer processes **finish** but do **not join**, no errors are raised and the script runs infinitely, stuck in limbo on the `join` statment?

I am aiming to speed up a data retrieval process, however I do not know how many 'tasks' (pieces of data to retrieve) there might be. So I made a modified version of the poison pill method so that the task recognizes when it is no longer retrieving information, and triggers the poison pill `if` statement.

I have posted a **proof**, which is a working example of my poison pill method, and a **full script**, which as the name implies is the full script. (both should be able to run as is)

**proof**:

```
import multiprocessing


class Task:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __call__(self):
        """Find officer and company data and combine and save it"""

        try:
            # 'gather some data!'
            self.result = self.number*2
            print(self.number)
            # 'fake' finding no data
            if self.result >= 8:
                raise NameError
        except NameError:
            # become poison pill once latest is done
            self.result = None

    def output(self):
        return self.result


class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    """Handle process and re-queue complete tasks"""
    def __init__(self, waiting_queue, complete_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.waiting_queue = waiting_queue
        self.complete_queue = complete_queue

    def run(self):
        """process tasks until queue is empty"""
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            current_task = self.waiting_queue.get()
            current_task()
            if current_task.output() is None:
                print('{}: Exiting, poison pill reached'.format(proc_name))
                self.waiting_queue.task_done()
                break
            self.waiting_queue.task_done()
            self.complete_queue.put(current_task)
        print('{}: complete'.format(proc_name))


class Shepard:
    """Handle life cycle of Consumers, Queues and Tasks"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, start_point):

        # initialize queues
        todo = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        finished = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

        # start consumers
        num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
        consumers = [Consumer(todo, finished) for i in range(num_consumers)]
        for q in consumers:
            q.start()

        # decide on (max) end limit (make much longer than suspected amount of data to be gathered
        start = int(start_point)
        max_record_range = 100
        end = start + max_record_range

        # Enqueue jobs
        for i in range(start, end):
            todo.put(Task(i))
        print('Processes joining')
        # wait for processes to join
        for p in consumers:
            p.join()
        print('Processes joined')

        # process results - UNFINISHED
        pass

        # return results - UNFINISHED
        return 'results!'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # load start points:
    start_points = {'cat1': 1, 'cat2': 3, 'cat3': 4}


    master = Shepard()
    cat1 = master(start_points['cat1'])
    print('cat1 done')
    cat2 = master(start_points['cat2'])
    print('cat2 done')
    cat3 = master(start_points['cat3'])
```

So here is the **full script**:

```
import time
import requests
import sys
import json
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import queue


class CompaniesHouseRequest:
    """Retreive information from Companies House"""
    def __init__(self, company, catagory_url=''):
        """Example URL: '/officers'"""
        self.company = str(company)
        self.catagory_url = str(catagory_url)

    def retrieve(self, key='Rn7RLDV9Tw9v4ShDCotjDtJFBgp1Lr4d-9GRYZMo'):
        """retrieve data from Companies House"""
        call = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/' + self.company + self.catagory_url
        retrieve_complete = False
        while retrieve_complete is False:
            resp = requests.get(call, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(key, ''))
            code = resp.status_code
            if code == 404:
                print(resp.status_code)
                raise NameError('Company not found')
            elif code == 200:
                try:
                    self.data = json.loads(resp.content.decode('UTF8'))
                    retrieve_complete = True
                except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                    print('Decode Error in Officers!')
            else:
                print("Error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                print('Retrying')
                time.sleep(5)
        return self.data


class Company:
    """Retrieve and hold company details"""
    def __init__(self, company_number):
        self.company_number = company_number

    def __call__(self):
        """Create request and process data"""
        # make request
        req = CompaniesHouseRequest(self.company_number)
        data = req.retrieve()
        # extract data
        try:
            line = [self.company_number,
                    data['company_name'],
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('premises', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('address_line_1', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('address_line_2', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('country', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('locality', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('postal_code', ''),
                    data['registered_office_address'].get('region', '')]
        except KeyError:
            line = ['' for i in range(0, 9)]
        # save as pandas dataframe
        return pd.DataFrame([line], columns=['company_number', 'company_name', 'company_address_premises',
                                             'company_address_line_1', 'company_address_line_2',
                                             'company_address_country', 'company_address_locality',
                                             'company_address_postcode', 'company_address_region'])


def name_splitter(name):
    split = name.split(', ')
    if len(split) > 2:
        return [split[2], split[1], split[0]]
    else:
        return ['', split[1], split[0]]


class Officers:
    """Retrieve and hold officers details"""
    def __init__(self, company_number):
        self.company_number = company_number

    def __call__(self):
        """Create request and process data"""
        # make request
        req = CompaniesHouseRequest(self.company_number, '/officers')
        data = req.retrieve()
        # extract data
        for officer in data['items']:
            if officer['officer_role'] == 'director':
                name = name_splitter(officer['name'])
                line = [name[0],
                        name[1],
                        name[2],
                        officer.get('occupation'),
                        officer.get('country_of_residence'),
                        officer.get('nationality'),
                        officer.get('appointed_on', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('premises', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('address_line_1', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('address_line_2', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('country', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('locality', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('postal_code', ''),
                        officer['address'].get('region', '')]
                break
        director_count = sum(map(lambda x: x['officer_role'] == 'director', data['items']))
        if director_count > 1:
            line += [True]
        elif director_count == 1:
            line += [False]
        else:
            line = ['no directors'] * 3 + [''] * 12
        return pd.DataFrame([line], columns=['title', 'first_name', 'surname', 'occupation', 'country_of_residence',
                                             'nationality', 'appointed_on',
                                             'address_premises', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2',
                                             'address_country', 'address_locality', 'address_postcode',
                                             'address_region', 'multi_director'])


class Task:
    def __init__(self, prefix, company_number):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.company_number = company_number

    def __call__(self):
        """Find officer and company data and combine and save it"""
        comp_id = self.prefix + str(self.company_number)
        print(comp_id)
        try:
            # initialise company class
            comp = Company(comp_id)
            # initialise officer class
            off = Officers(comp_id)
            # retrieve and concatonate
            self.result = pd.concat([comp(), off()], axis=1)

        except NameError:
            # become poison pill once latest is done
            self.result = None

    def output(self):
        return self.result


class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    """Handle process and re-queue complete tasks"""
    def __init__(self, waiting_queue, complete_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.waiting_queue = waiting_queue
        self.complete_queue = complete_queue

    def run(self):
        """process tasks until queue is empty"""
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            current_task = self.waiting_queue.get()
            current_task()
            if current_task.output() is None:
                print('{}: Exiting, poison pill reached'.format(proc_name))
                self.waiting_queue.task_done()
                break
            self.waiting_queue.task_done()
            self.complete_queue.put(current_task)
        print('{}: complete'.format(proc_name))


class Shepard:
    """Handle life of Consumers, Queues and Tasks"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, prefix, start_point):

        # initialize queues
        todo = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        finished = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

        # start consumers
        num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
        consumers = [Consumer(todo, finished) for i in range(num_consumers)]
        for q in consumers:
            q.start()

        # decide on (max) end limit
        start = int(start_point)
        max_record_range = 1000
        end = start + max_record_range

        # Enqueue jobs
        for i in range(start, end):
            todo.put(Task(prefix, i))
        print('Processes joining')

        # wait for processes to join
        for p in consumers:
            p.join()
        print('Processes joined')

        # process results - UNFINISHED
        pass

        # return results - UNFINISHED
        return 'results!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # paths to data
    data_directory = r'C:\Users\hdewinton\OneDrive - Advanced Payment Solutions\Python\Corporate DM\data'
    base = r'\base'

    # load start points:
    init = {"England": 10926071, "Scotland": 574309, "Ireland": 647561}

    # gather data for each catagory
    master = Shepard()
    ireland = master('NI', init['Ireland'])
    scotland = master('SC', init['Scotland'])
    england = master('', init['England'])
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: There is no error, the consumers run up until their last print statment but fail to join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** - the *consequence* (getting stuck in limbo while the consumers fail to join) can be fixed by changing this:

```
finished = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
```

to this:

```
mananger = multiprocessing.Manager()
finished = mananger.Queue()
```

**Details** - "When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe. This has some consequences which are a little surprising, but should not cause any practical difficulties – if they really bother you then you can instead use a queue created with a manager." from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

The second queue, of finished items, triggers one of the aforementioned *surprising consquences* if a certain number of tasks are added to it. Below the limit there are no problems and above the limit the *consequence* occurs. This does not occur in the dummy because the second queue, while present, is not used. The limit depends on the size and complexity of the `Task` objects, so I recon this has something to do with the flushing of pickled data only occurring after a certain volume of data is reached - the volume of data triggers this *consequence*

**Addendum** - Another error also appears once the fix has been implemented: a pipe error occurs as the consumers of the `todo` queue are terminated before the queue
is empty leaving the pipe within the queue object with no connection object to send data to. This triggers a `WinError 232`. Not to worry though, the pipe error can be fixed by emptying the queue before exiting the consumers.
Simply add this to the consumers class run method:

```
while not self.waiting_queue.empty():
            try:
                self.waiting_queue.get(timeout=0.001)
            except:
                pass
        self.waiting_queue.close()
```

this removes every element from the queue, make sure its after the main `while` loop and the pipe error should not occur because the consumers will empty the will queue before terminating.

Comment: This solves my problem. But why mananger.Queue() works while Queue not?